# Can i publish mobile app which is using other website url (i.e. www.youtube.com) into mobile stores

Tags: android, mobile, windows-phone-8.1, google-play

I am new in mobile development and unsure about license,privacy policies etc in different mobile stores, just to have a mobile app flavour i wanted to create mobile app which uses other website url internally, basically to give a App view for a url,

so just wanted to check is this illegal to use other companies url in my app and publish into mobile market?? for example using www.youtube.com from my app

Comment: Check their Terms of Service.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is not. But website like youtube.com allows public users and agreed to embedding their resources on your owns. It means it can be used by everyone .

Some websites are also providing public links and widgets for agreeing to use of their services to be integrated.

But most of them (that your mobile store can't verify) are requiring data and legal sheets for displaying their resource while submitting publish. Exactly is Apple and Google store always looking and checking at that.

The most restricted object I aware is Video.

I 'd like you to suggest that you should request to original owner and make a digital agreement first. And try it to publish.